# How to extract a string between two of the SAME delimiters T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I'm wanting to extract part of a string from a value which has a number of the same delimiters.

Here is an example of the data I am working with (these file paths could be even longer depending on the depth of the file):

FilePath:

Q:\12345\downloads\randomfilename.png

Q:\123_4566\downloads\randomfilename.pdf

Q:\CCCMUD\downloads\randomfilename.mp4

I want to extract part of the string between the first two delimiters ( \ )  for every row into a new column e.g.

12345

123_4566

CCCMUD

I know I need to be using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX but I'm not sure how. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I believe the question has been answered correctly by 'Salman A' below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CHAR_INDEX` twice:

```sql
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(path, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1)
FROM tests
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('\', path), 0)) AS ca1(pos1)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('\', path, pos1 + 1), 0)) AS ca2(pos2)

-- NULLIF is used to convert 0 value (character not found) to NULL
```

[Test on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97f24eb30db7ee049e9d50b31d885c9a)

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I was looking for! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In all your examples, the first `\` is at character 3 in the string.  If so, then you can simply use:

```
select v.*,
       substring(filepath, 4, charindex('\', filepath, 4) - 4)
from (values ('Q:\123_4566\downloads\randomfilename.pdf')) v(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @s table (path varchar(4000));

INSERT @s(path) VALUES
  ('Q:\12345\downloads\randomfilename.png'),
  ('Q:\123_4566\downloads\randomfilename.pdf'),
  ('Q:\CCCMUD\downloads\randomfilename.mp4');

SELECT folder = LEFT(o, CHARINDEX('\', o) - 1) FROM 
(
  SELECT o = SUBSTRING(path, CHARINDEX('\', path) + 1, 4000)
  FROM @s
) AS o;
```

Output:

```
folder
----------
12345
123_4566
CCCMUD
```

This will error, though, for paths that don't contain two `\` characters. So you may want to add a filter to the inner query (or determine how you want to handle the output differently in that case):

```
WHERE path LIKE '%\%\%'
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy and efficient way to do this is to use an ordinal splitter ([like this one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function)).  To make sure the split value only contains numbers you could add `WHERE try_cast(ds.Item as int) is not null`.  Something like this

splitter

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

query

```
select ds.*
from @s s
     cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(s.[path], '\') ds
where ds.ItemNumber=2
      and try_cast(ds.Item as int) is not null;
```

```
ItemNumber  Item
2           12345
```