# How to extract part of a string numerous times between delimiters and input into new columns T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I want to extract part of a string numerous times from a value which has a number of the same delimiters and place the extracted strings into new columns.

Here is an example of the data I am working with (these folder paths could be even longer depending on the depth of the folder):

FolderPath:

```
Q:\downloads\extraction\bee\honey\
Q:\desktop\chocolate\london\time\spring\
Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\
```

I want to extract the whole string between delimiters from the left and place them into new columns at different stages of the string e.g.

| FolderPath | RootDirectory | SubDirectory | SubSubDirectory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\ | Q:\documents | Q:\documents\cars | Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin |

I'm just wondering if this is possible, especially when folders names have all types of different lengths.

Any help would me much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: How many subsubdirectories can you have?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Having `STRING_SPLIT`/`STRING_AGG` will make this easier than not having them.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I think the furthest I need to go is 4 directories deep, so it might be: RootDirectory, SubDirectory, SubSubDirectory, SubSubSubDirectory for example

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's version 15.0.2000.5

Comment: If you don't know that for sure, that's a big problem. The sql language has a very strict requirement to know the number of columns in the result set at the outset of the query, _before looking at any data_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ah okay. I'll keep the directories at level 3 which means answering the example in the question will be sufficient - many thanks.

Comment: The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69028444/92546) question should help you get part way there. Show your work and where you get stuck and we can help you from there.

Comment: @AdamCraven fix the title. All caps means screaming and is just harder to read

Comment: @AdamCraven as for the question, SQL in general and T-SQL in particular are terrible at text manipulation. T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions either. It's a *lot* easier to parse paths on the client. Or you can write a SQLCLR function in C# to parse paths.

Comment: @AdamCraven `15.0.2000.5` that's SQL Server 2019 RTM, ie unpatched. Why don't you patch the server? Do you *want* to have to deal with bugs? In any case, `STRING_SPLIT` is available BUT the order of the results isn't guaranteed. SQL Server 2017 and later can use Python scripts though. This won't be as fast as a SQLCLR function.

Comment: @AdamCraven you *can't* have an arbitrary number of columns in a result set either. You have to know how many columns need to be displayed from the start - how are you going to read their values if you don't know their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED (with a 2nd solution)**

**Solution #1 - Charindex + cascading APPLY:**

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @folders TABLE (Folder VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT  @folders VALUES
('Q:\downloads\extraction\bee\honey\'),
('Q:\desktop\chocolate\london\time\spring\'),
('Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\');

SELECT      FolderParse.*
FROM        @folders AS f
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    FolderPath      = f.Folder,
    RootDirectory   = SUBSTRING(f.Folder, 1, p2.Pos-2),
    SubDirectory    = SUBSTRING(f.Folder, 1, p3.Pos-1),
    SubSubDirectory = SUBSTRING(f.Folder, 1, p4.Pos-1)
  FROM        (VALUES(CHARINDEX('\',f.Folder)))          AS p1(Pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('\',f.Folder,p1.Pos+1))) AS p2(Pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('\',f.Folder,p2.Pos+1))) AS p3(Pos)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('\',f.Folder,p3.Pos+1))) AS p4(Pos)
) AS folderParse;
```

**Results:**

```
FolderPath                                RootDirectory  SubDirectory            SubSubDirectory
----------------------------------------- -------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------
Q:\downloads\extraction\bee\honey\        Q:\downloads   Q:\downloads\extraction Q:\downloads\extraction\bee
Q:\desktop\chocolate\london\time\spring\  Q:\desktop     Q:\desktop\chocolate    Q:\desktop\chocolate\london
Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\   Q:\documents   Q:\documents\cars       Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin
```

Solution #2 - Tally Table:

The first solution is the way to go but this second one is better for when you need to go much deeper. For this you need to grab a copy of [fnTally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally).

Here's how to do it against one string:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) =  'Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\';

SELECT
  FolderPath      = @string,
  RootDirectory   = MAX(CASE f.RN WHEN 1 THEN f.FPath END),
  SubDirectory    = MAX(CASE f.RN WHEN 2 THEN f.FPath END),
  SubSubDirectory = MAX(CASE f.RN WHEN 3 THEN f.FPath END)
FROM
(
  SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.N), SUBSTRING(@string,1,t.N+2)
  FROM        (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,4,1000))) AS s(Txt)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(1,LEN(s.Txt))           AS t
  WHERE       SUBSTRING(s.Txt,t.N,1) = '\'
) AS f(RN,FPath);
```

**Returns:**

```
FolderPath                               RootDirectory      SubDirectory          SubSubDirectory
---------------------------------------- ------------------ --------------------- --------------------------------
Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\  Q:\documents       Q:\documents\cars     Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin
```

**Against a table:**

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @folders TABLE (Folder VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT  @folders VALUES
('Q:\downloads\extraction\bee\honey\'),
('Q:\desktop\chocolate\london\time\spring\'),
('Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\');

--==== Solution
SELECT DirectoryParse.* 
FROM   @folders AS fld
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    FolderPath      = fld.Folder,
    RootDirectory   = MAX(CASE f.RN WHEN 1 THEN f.FPath END),
    SubDirectory    = MAX(CASE f.RN WHEN 2 THEN f.FPath END),
    SubSubDirectory = MAX(CASE f.RN WHEN 3 THEN f.FPath END)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.N), SUBSTRING(fld.Folder,1,t.N+2)
    FROM        (VALUES(SUBSTRING(fld.Folder,4,1000))) AS s(Txt)
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(1,LEN(s.Txt))           AS t
    WHERE       SUBSTRING(s.Txt,t.N,1) = '\'
  ) AS f(RN,FPath)
) AS DirectoryParse;
```

**Results:**

```
FolderPath                                RootDirectory  SubDirectory            SubSubDirectory
----------------------------------------- -------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------
Q:\downloads\extraction\bee\honey\        Q:\downloads   Q:\downloads\extraction Q:\downloads\extraction\bee
Q:\desktop\chocolate\london\time\spring\  Q:\desktop     Q:\desktop\chocolate    Q:\desktop\chocolate\london
Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin\vanquish\   Q:\documents   Q:\documents\cars       Q:\documents\cars\astonmartin
```